# MailChimp - Optin via my website ( how do i add via the API)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, mailchimp

I have a website that users subscribe into,

How can i add them to a list in the API of mailchimp without sending (the redundant) opt-in email to them?

The only field thier api (v2.0) is accepting is disable-double-opt-in which does not affect the welcome email)

Comment: Do you want to disable the welcome e-mail or the opt-in e-mail?

Comment: Jacob, I would like to disable the opt-in e-mail. (Can it be done by the API? Can it be done by the account configuration? Can it be done by validating your company Terms and conditions in the website with mailchimp?)

Answer (score 0):

Try the api doc for update_existing: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php

If you are using a wrapper (in your case I guess the node.js wrapper), you would use the method *batchSubscribe()* or just *subscribe()* and pass at least the following params to the method:

```
params["double_optin"] = false;
params["update_existing"] = true;
```

to update already added subscribers.

For new users, the double_optin should be enough. How are you trying to send the data?

Comment: What @jacob-budin says: then the param you're looking for is
     params["send_welcome"] = false;